# Can't run open-vm-tools on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vmware

I'm trying to enable shared folders on Ubuntu Server 14.04, however following all the guides and posts I've found online have been of no help.

when trying to mount `vmhgfs` I get the "device not found" error, seems that module isn't loaded.

After installing `open-vm-tools`, I am unable to run `vmware-config-tools.pl`, I get the error "command not found". I've tried following various guides about updates Linux headers, etc. and have been unable to get the config tools to appear.

How do I get the shared folders mounted?

Comment: `vmware-config-tools.pl` is not part of the open-vm-tools package.  If you issue the command `vmware-hgfsclient`what do you get as a result?

Comment: I get the name of the shared folder from the host

Comment: After much trying, I was unable to get open-vm-tools to mount an hgfs directory also, and reverted to the tools which came with VMWare.  I'm still looking, but some sites suggest that Debian and thus Ubuntu do not really support open-vm-tools very well.

Comment: when attempting to install vmware tools, it failed telling me they aren't supported and to use open-vm-tools instead

Comment: I understand and blew past the same error, and got a working system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `vmhgfs` modules of `open-vm-tools` currently have some problems with compilation which have not been resolved as of 12-19-2015 [Trusty](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/open-vm-tools/+bug/1513647) and [Vivid](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/open-vm-tools/+bug/1500581) both are affected by similar issues.

The currect work-around is to use the `vmtools` supplied by VMWare, however upon installation the tools will detect that `open-vm-tools` is available and indicate that this is a preferred solution.  The user will need to override the deault answer (no, don't install) to cause installation of the `vmware-tools`.

If `vmware-tools` from a version prior to version 12 are used, the user will also have to apply patches to the `vmware-tools` module.  These patches are available at [github](https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches) along with comprehensive instructions for application of the patches in the [readme](https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches/blob/master/README.md) file.

For brevity:

Download the patches:

```
git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches.git
```

Obtain the lates version of the vmware-tools:

```
cd vmware-tools-patches
./download-tools.sh 8.1.0
```

Untar and apply the patches

```
./untar-and-patch.sh
```

Compile and install the patched files.

```
./compile.sh
```

Comment: That worked for me. But I used /download-tools.sh latest to install latest version of these patches.

Answer (score 2):

Quick alternative,
I had many issues with open-vm-tools on Ubuntu 14.04 and then on Ubuntu 16.04. I tried to install it from my VMware host and from Ubuntu package open-vm-tools, but finally I could fix many of my problems installing open-vm-tools-desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop
```

[See the VMWare website for more information about this package](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2073803)

Comment: Finally! open-vm-tools did nothing here, but I can confirm this method also works well with Ubuntu derivatives like elementary OS 0.4. :)